# sort table based on index with b-buttons (up and down)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm working with `BootstrapVue`.

I have a `table` where I can input rows with my `b-button`. After inserting different rows I want to have a - I will name it **sort function**.

So I want to be able to change the order with two buttons (*here: `Up` and `Down`*) based on their `index`. So the index should always be the same but the `ID` should switch.

Also I have - if my index is equal to zero - disabled the button because I could not be able to go "higher". This I also want on the last element..

Thanks for helping me out!

This is how it looks for better understanding:

[image]

**INFO** You should be able to copy paste the code and it should work.

*Code of template*

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-button @click="addNewItem()">Add Input</b-button>

    <h3 class="mt-5 ml-3 mb-2"><strong>Created Table</strong></h3>
        <table class="table table-striped col-md-12 mt-4">
          <tr>
            <div class="row mt-2 mb-2">
              <th class="col-md-1 ml-4">INDEX</th>
              <th class="col-md-1">ID</th>
              <th class="col-md-1">CHANGE #</th>
            </div>
          </tr>
          <tr v-for="(item, index) in inputs" :key="item.id">
            <div class="row mt-2 mb-2">
              <td class="col-md-1 ml-4">#{{ index + 1 }}</td>
              <td class="col-md-1 mr-1">{{item.id}}</td>
              <td class="col-md-3">
                <b-button :disabled="index == 0" size="sm mr-1">Up</b-button>
                <b-button size="sm">Down</b-button>
              </td>
            </div>
          </tr>
        </table>

  </div>
</template>
```

*Code of script*

```
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        inputs: [{
          id: 1
        }],
        id: 1,
      }
    },

    methods: {
      addNewItem() {
        this.inputs.push({
          id: this.id += 1
        })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you attempted anything yet? The **INFO** line makes me think this is homework. Is this homework?

Comment: actually it's not homework, haha. The **INFO** is just for information that I reduced my code to the basics that everyone is able to copy paste it to run it and that my problem is easier to understand.

Comment: actually i haven't done anything yet, because I don't know how to start right now. This would be enough for me ..

Comment: I see, sorry :) The first thing you need to do is add click handlers to your buttons. These need to send along the index and direction obviously. The handler functions then need to change the array based on these two parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is self-explanatory ..

*TEMPLATE*

```
<b-button :disabled="index == 0" @click="sortUp(index)"><b-icon icon="arrow-up"></b-icon></b-button>
<b-button :disabled="index == (inputs.length - 1)" size="sm"><b-icon icon="arrow-down" @click="sortDown(index)"></b-icon></b-button>
```

*SCRIPT*

```
sortUp(index) {
  var element = this.inputs[index];
  this.inputs.splice(index, 1);
  this.inputs.splice(index-1, 0, element);
},

sortDown(index) {
  var element = this.inputs[index];
  this.inputs.splice(index, 1);
  this.inputs.splice(index+1, 0, element);
},
```